# WordPress theme sub menu does not show up

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to WordPress.  I am using All Tuts theme

In the custom menu, I added all the categories and subcategories. I arranged them in a proper way up to down left to right. Sub categories are a little right under its parent category. I did save the menu. When I refresh the browser and i put my mouse over a parent category no sub-category showed up.

When I see the editor, the menu does appear in some Theme Function file as I showed below. I just can't understand this kind of code. I need help, please.  Thanks.

functions.php

```
 /*******************************
     MENUS SUPPORT
    ********************************/
    if ( function_exists( 'wp_nav_menu' ) ){
        if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
            add_theme_support('nav-menus');
            add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
            function register_my_menus() {
                register_nav_menus(
                    array(
                        'primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
                        'secondary-menu' => __( 'Secondary Menu' )
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

style.css

```
/* TopMenu */
.ddsmoothmenu {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:6px;
    border-right:1px solid #2F2F2F;
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li {
    float:left;
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li a{
    display:block;
    color:#ccc;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-left:1px solid #2F2F2F;
    height:42px;
    line-height:42px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:11px;
    padding:0 12px;
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li a:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background:url(images/bk_top_hover.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
}
```

header.php

```
<!-- drop down top menu init -->
<script type="text/javascript">
ddsmoothmenu.init({
    mainmenuid: "topMenu", //menu DIV id
    orientation: 'h', //Horizontal or vertical menu: Set to "h" or "v"
    classname: 'ddsmoothmenu', //class added to menu's outer DIV
    //customtheme: ["#1c5a80", "#18374a"],
    contentsource: "markup" //"markup" or ["container_id", "path_to_menu_file"]
})


<?php if ( function_exists( 'wp_nav_menu' ) ){
                    wp_nav_menu( array( 
                    'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
                    'container_id' => 'topMenu', 
                    'container_class' => 'ddsmoothmenu',
                    'fallback_cb'=>'primarymenu')
                     );
        }else{
            primarymenu();
        }?>

        <!-- End #topMenu -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your template file for a `wp_nav_menu` call like this:

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) ) {
                                    ... could be lots of args here...
                                    'menu' => 'primary-menu', 
                                    'depth'           => 1,
                                    'theme_location' => 'primary-menu')); 
}
```

My suggestion would be to look for the depth argument, and change it to 2, if you want two levels of submenus.

Comment: has_nav_menu( ) is called no where in the template files

Comment: How about your header.php file?  That's typically where the main navigation would be.

Comment: i found the function in header.php
i changed the depth to 2
Still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

[image: Setting the menu]

Make sure you have the menu set to be the one that shows like the screenshot above.

Comment: name of my menu is 'catg'
I have set 'catg' to be the Primary Navigation in the theme location area

Comment: Then you need to change the function you posted above to reflect that.  Or change your menu name to Primary Menu.  If you opt to change the function, change `'primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),` to `'primary-menu' => __( 'catg' ),`.  You should change the menu name though.